# BibLaTeX is not working due to a strange error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am writing currently my thesis with TeXlive 2016 and TeXstudio 2.11 as editor. (I tried TeXworks, but as expected this changed nothing.) I installed TeXlive with the installation script about 2 months ago. I updated everything with the TeXlive Manager recently.

When trying to create a bibliography, I stumbled over the strange error during compilation:

> (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)) !
>   Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      D l.6 \bibliography
>                    {Bibliography} ?

A minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\begin{document}
   test
\end{document}
```

Adding a `\bibliography` and `\cite` commands did not change anything.

When I switch to `natbib` everything works fine, except the missing possibility for customization.

The output of console:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle-icomp.bbx
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle-icomp.cbx)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   D
l.6 \bibliography
                 {Bibliography}
?
```

And the logfile:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.6)  9 JAN 2017 09:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box26
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 130.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 131.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 132.
Package scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `11pt'.
(scrartcl)             This is correct!
(scrartcl)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=11pt'.
(scrartcl)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl)             you'd have to use `fontsize=11pt' there
(scrartcl)             instead of `11pt', too.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 2052.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1529.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 4036.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip53
\belowcaptionskip=\skip54
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box27
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 5049.
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def
File: latin1.def 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
Language: german 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (traditional orthogra
phy)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
Language: germanb 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (traditional orthogr
aphy)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 139.
)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count90

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write3
\integerpart=\count91
\decimalpart=\count92
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count93
\c@listtotal=\count94
\c@listcount=\count95
\c@liststart=\count96
\c@liststop=\count97
\c@citecount=\count98
\c@citetotal=\count99
\c@multicitecount=\count100
\c@multicitetotal=\count101
\c@instcount=\count102
\c@maxnames=\count103
\c@minnames=\count104
\c@maxitems=\count105
\c@minitems=\count106
\c@citecounter=\count107
\c@savedcitecounter=\count108
\c@uniquelist=\count109
\c@uniquename=\count110
\c@refsection=\count111
\c@refsegment=\count112
\c@maxextratitle=\count113
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count114
\c@maxextrayear=\count115
\c@maxextraalpha=\count116
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count117
\c@highnamepenalty=\count118
\c@lownamepenalty=\count119
\c@maxparens=\count120
\c@parenlevel=\count121
\blx@tempcnta=\count122
\blx@tempcntb=\count123
\blx@tempcntc=\count124
\blx@maxsection=\count125
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count126
\blx@notetype=\count127
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count128
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count129
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count130
\labelnumberwidth=\skip55
\labelalphawidth=\skip56
\biblabelsep=\skip57
\bibitemsep=\skip58
\bibnamesep=\skip59
\bibinitsep=\skip60
\bibparsep=\skip61
\bibhang=\skip62
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write4
\c@mincomprange=\count131
\c@maxcomprange=\count132
\c@mincompwidth=\count133
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authortitle-icomp.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count134
\c@savedafterword=\count135
\c@annotator=\count136
\c@savedannotator=\count137
\c@author=\count138
\c@savedauthor=\count139
\c@bookauthor=\count140
\c@savedbookauthor=\count141
\c@commentator=\count142
\c@savedcommentator=\count143
\c@editor=\count144
\c@savededitor=\count145
\c@editora=\count146
\c@savededitora=\count147
\c@editorb=\count148
\c@savededitorb=\count149
\c@editorc=\count150
\c@savededitorc=\count151
\c@foreword=\count152
\c@savedforeword=\count153
\c@holder=\count154
\c@savedholder=\count155
\c@introduction=\count156
\c@savedintroduction=\count157
\c@namea=\count158
\c@savednamea=\count159
\c@nameb=\count160
\c@savednameb=\count161
\c@namec=\count162
\c@savednamec=\count163
\c@translator=\count164
\c@savedtranslator=\count165
\c@shortauthor=\count166
\c@savedshortauthor=\count167
\c@shorteditor=\count168
\c@savedshorteditor=\count169
\c@labelname=\count170
\c@savedlabelname=\count171
\c@institution=\count172
\c@savedinstitution=\count173
\c@lista=\count174
\c@savedlista=\count175
\c@listb=\count176
\c@savedlistb=\count177
\c@listc=\count178
\c@savedlistc=\count179
\c@listd=\count180
\c@savedlistd=\count181
\c@liste=\count182
\c@savedliste=\count183
\c@listf=\count184
\c@savedlistf=\count185
\c@location=\count186
\c@savedlocation=\count187
\c@organization=\count188
\c@savedorganization=\count189
\c@origlocation=\count190
\c@savedoriglocation=\count191
\c@origpublisher=\count192
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count193
\c@publisher=\count194
\c@savedpublisher=\count195
\c@language=\count196
\c@savedlanguage=\count197
\c@pageref=\count198
\c@savedpageref=\count199
\shorthandwidth=\skip63
\shortjournalwidth=\skip64
\shortserieswidth=\skip65
\shorttitlewidth=\skip66
\shortauthorwidth=\skip67
\shorteditorwidth=\skip68
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def DATE vVERSION biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def DATE vVERSION biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
\c@textcitecount=\count266
\c@textcitetotal=\count267
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count268
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count269
\c
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Show the log-file of the compilation.

Comment: That should work, but note that `\bibliography{foo}` is deprecated in favour of `\addbibresource{foo.bib}` (the old syntax, however, still works and should not be the cause of such an error).

Comment: Any news here? Did you get your code working? Try deleting all auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`) and show us the log files (`.log` and `.blg`). Currently we can't really answer your question since the problem is not reproducible from the code given in the question.

Comment: I added the information in the original question. I deleted all of the temporary files at first, but that did not help.

Comment: Exactly how have you installed `biblatex`? The log shows you've got a development version (no version numbers), not a release one!

Comment: I noticed that using the development version right from github, where indeed certain version numbers are not filled in give exactly the error you describe. How did you install `biblatex`? Can you install and update `biblatex` via the normal channels (`tlmgr`)?

Answer (score 2):

My bad... I updated the package manually with the github version, as the tlmgr did not work properly behind the proxy server in my company. After reverting the update and updating to a released version everything works fine! Thanks!